# Connect Zendesk to AWS cognito for authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml, zendesk

I have a react application which uses Amplify to connect to AWS cognito userpool. I wanted to connect zendesk to this userpool using SAML, so that any user, logged into my react application should automatically get logged into zendesk.
I went through [zendesk's](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408887505690) documentation for SSO and it supports SAML based authentication. But on congito side, it doesn't support SAML as an Identity Provider.
Can somebody please help me understand the right way of connecting these two applications?